Adjusting contents of frame in Tkinter grid layout using python
My aim is to stack a list of entries horizontally in a frame using thenTkinter grid layout.
Here is my code:
from tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        frtop=self.winfo_toplevel() #Flexible Toplevel of the window
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        print("width="+str(screen_width)+", height="+str(screen_height))
        max_windows_size=str(screen_width)+"x"+str(screen_height)
        frtop.geometry(max_windows_size)
        self.grid()
        self.table_frame = Frame(self)
        self.table_frame.grid(column =0, row =0,sticky='NSEW')
        self.table_headers_title = ['','Description','Quantity','Rate', 'Amt','pending']
        self.total_columns = len(self.table_headers_title)
        self.table_headers=[]
        for j in range(self.total_columns):
            self.data_tbl = Entry(self.table_frame,  fg='blue', font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
            self.table_headers.append(self.data_tbl)
            self.table_frame.grid_columnconfigure(j, weight=1)
            self.data_tbl.grid(row=0, column=j)
            self.data_tbl.insert(0, self.table_headers_title[j])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global app
    app = Application()
    app.master.title("Sample application")
    app.mainloop()

I am expecting that all entries will be of the same width and fully occupy the frame.
It is not happening. Actually , last column is 'pendi'.
What am I doing wrong?

hi OysterShucker , i ran your code . It had good hierarchy so i called master^4 of table when I put it in a scrollable frame . I request you again to put that code so that we can mark it as answer and close this post . Thanks .
